# Approval Emails sent from salesforce

Tags: email, approval-process, apex-email-service

Is there a way to get the log of all the Approval emails sent from Salesforce. I tried to get the log of all the emails sent out by requesting for email log, but for some reason feel like the data is missing. Is there a easy way to monitor all the approval hierarchy emails sent from SF to a specific/ all the users.

In short : Is there a archieve where I could go and see if the email notification was sent out for a specific user (I know this is a standard functionality, but the user complaints he never got an email :()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't, if it's not in the Email log it wasn't sent. If what you need is to "Prove" the action was performed, you could add a task as an approval action.

Comment: I think that would be a novel way to handle going forward, but its sad that there is no way to retrieve a sent email. I got a internal salesforce Id as part of the log file, can i call support and get some more info on the sobject id etc.. Do u have a clue if they would have more info based on internal Id>

Comment: I doubt support will provide you this. Unless, maybe you manage to get them to escalate the case to Tier 3 or R&D.(I used to work for Salesforce support). Ideally, the logs would contain information  of what process triggered the email but unfortunately that's not the case for now.

Comment: :(!!! Thats gonna suck if SF cannot help !!!:(

Answer (score 2):

Create another mailbox which get's CC'ed everytime an approval email is sent. You can configure this in the Setup - Email Settings.